# Mongodb calculate growth of multiple values. Mongo Query is preferred than Javascript

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb values like

```
    Date       Price
    28-7-2016  300
    27-7-2016  250
    26-7-2016  200
    25-7-2016  250
```

How to calculate the growth like (300 - 250)/250*100 for date 28-7-2016 & 27-7-2016.
The end result should be:

```
Date                     Growth
(28-7-2016)-(27-7-2016)   20%
(27-7-2016)-(26-7-2016)   25%
(26-7-2016)-(25-7-2016)   -20%
```

Comment: You can always fetch the dataset into the app and do your calculations there.

Comment: I am working only on mongodb. I am not using any app. That's why I have to do this way.

Comment: JFYI, `mongo` command-line console tool is a client app too. You can fetch a collection of records and enumerate/process them however you wish (you'll need to know some javascript).

Comment: can you show some examples of what you just said.?

Comment: Sure. In your mongo console do `var docs = db.mycollection.find({ foo: 'bar'}).toArray()`. Now `docs` is an array of all documents for which foo=bar. Since it is a javascript array, you're free to use all power of javascript to post-process this.

Comment: the reason i posted this question is it is very easy in javascript. and i wanted to do challenging task. but in any way can this be done in mongo aggregate query.?

Comment: You need the result or the challenge? I showed you a way to get the result. Saved the challenge for you :)

Comment: any hints of how to do it in mongo aggregate query?